# Determine and construct irreducible polynomial (of degree >3) over finite fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Wanted to determine whether a polynomial $x^p+...+a_0$ was irreducible.

The common sense came from that

> A polynomial of degree two or three over a field F was irreducible if and only if it had a root in $F$.

and

> A monic polynomial with integer coefficients and $p(d)\neq0$ for all integer dividing the constant term of $p(x)$, then $p(x)$ had no root in $Q$.

However, the first one only limited in polynomial of degree 2 or 3. The second one, like Eisenstein's Criterion and many others, was in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ or UFDs.

I also read an article in [Construction of Irreducible Polynomials over Finite Fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150646/construction-of-irreducible-polynomials-over-finite-fields) and the procedure was way too messy, and the remaining option seemed to actually calculated out all the possible outcomes.

My question was that:

1. Was there any theorems to determine polynomials irreducible or not in a finite field? (Especially, monic polynomials of degree 4 -6.)
2. Was there any other general procedure to create irreducible polynomials?

Comment: I once ran [Berlekamp's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm) by hand to prove that a polynomial was irreducible. No transformation was allowing Eisenstein, so I got rid of it that way. Last resource, I would say.

Comment: For practical purposes, use a computer algebra system such as Maple, which has quite efficient irreducibility tests for polynomials over finite fields.  If you generate a random monic polynomial of degree $d$ over the field of order $p^m$, the probability of its being irreducible is, I think, $1/d + O(p^{-dm/2})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few general algorithms for factoring polynomials over a finite field; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields#Factoring_algorithms).

To find all irreducible polynomials of degree $n$ over $\mathbb F_p$, factor $x^{p^n}-x$ mod $p$. See an example [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x%5E%7B3%5E4%7D-x+mod+3).

Comment: +1 thank you for the help. I was also wondering if there was some way to get around with the coefficients as a short cut.  i.e. $x^4+1$ was irreducible in $Z/3Z$. I wanted to know if we could in general to determine weather some simple polynomials such as $x^p++x+1$ was irreducible or not. (Notice that $1+x+$...$+x^{p-1}$ was irreducible in $Q[x]$ but can we find some similar trick to deal with them in finite fields?)

Answer (score 0):

Not a general method by any means, but here’s how to determine that $X^4+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb F_3$:

Notice that you’re asking for a fourth root of $-1$, in other words, for an eighth root of unity. This means you’re looking for a field $\Bbb F_q$, $q=3^m$, such that $8|(q-1)$. In this case, you’re looking for the smallest power $q=3^m$ of three such that $3^m\equiv1\pmod8$. That’s the fourth power, of course, and this means that if $\rho$ is a root of $X^4+1$, then $[\Bbb F_3(\rho):\Bbb F_3]=4$. In other words, $X^4+1$ is the minimal polynomial for $\rho$ over $\Bbb F_3$. So irreducible.

You can use this method to determine just how the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(X)$, which is $\Bbb Z$-irreducible, splits over $\Bbb F_q$, for any prime power $q$ that’s relatively prime to $n$.

Comment: $X^4+1$ is reducible over any $\mathbb F_p$ where $p$ is a prime. See [here](https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/an-irreducible-integral-polynomial-reducible-over-all-finite-prime-fields/). And in $\mathbb F_3$ we have $X^4+1=(X^2-X-1)(X^2+X-1)$. Also $3^2\equiv1\pmod8$.

Comment: And my answer was *completely* wrong, @mathcounterexamples.net . I said “of course” to state a foul lie, since the smallest power $q=3^m$ such that $3^n\equiv1\pmod8$ is certainly $m=2$. I would give myself a -1 for that if I were allowed to vote against (or for) myself. Why don’t you give my “answer” a minus one?

Comment: Overall, I don't like to downvote. Everyone is subject to mistakes and I prefer comments!

Comment: I don’t like to downvote either, @mathcounterexamples.net , but this answer was so bad that it merits a sharp rap on the knuckles at the very least.

Comment: @[Lubin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/17760/lubin) Thanks for letting me know the expression *a sharp rap on the knuckles*! I'll try to remember it.